# could not able to gettign the user_params[:roles] in my controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, angular

From my agular 2 front application I have send a parameter called `roles` to my api using the following line of codes

### Angular2 Front end request

```
createNewUser(model: User) {
    var params = JSON.stringify({
      first_name: model.first_name,
      last_name: model.last_name,
      email: model.email,
      contact_number: model.contact_number,
      user_name: model.user_name,
      password: model.password,
      roles: model.roles
    });
    console.log("From Service " + params);
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3003/api/users',params, {headers : headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

from this code you have observerd I have sending a parameter name `roles` to the rails api.

At the side of API I have received this parameter

### Rails Console Outupt

Processing by UsersController#create as JSON

```
  Parameters: {"first_name"=>"nifras", "last_name"=>"ismail", "email"=>"nifrasismail@gmail.com", "contact_number"=>"3778990300", "user_name"=>"ffgfg", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "roles"=>[0, 1], "user"=>{"first_name"=>"nifras", "last_name"=>"ismail", "email"=>"nifrasismail@gmail.com", "contact_number"=>"3778990300", "user_name"=>"ffgfg", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

From the controllers I have tried on to getting the value of Roles but it does not show nothing. but If i getting other values it returns the value. why it is fails on my controller

### My Controller user_params method

```
def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :contact_number, :user_name, :password, :roles)
    end
```

I'm trying to getting the values from the below line of codes

```
puts(user_params[:first_name]) # ==> nifras
puts(user_params[:roles] # nothing will return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `:roles` under `:user` so either add roles in form under user fields or `permit` the params without `.require(:user)`

```
params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :contact_number, :user_name, :password, roles: [])
```

Comment: how do i get  the role it inside the :user

Comment: You need to move it under theform in your view

Comment: Sorry I could not understand. Could you please explain on the code level

Comment: Can you please tell me from where your params under `user` are coming

Comment: view or some other file

Comment: I create a user model and controller from the template of command `rails g scaffold User first_name:string...........` without the attribute roles. Then I create a Role from the same method I have mentioned. then I do a many-to-many migration. using command `rails g migration CreateJoinTableRoleUser roles users`

Comment: The whole things are working fine. Now I adding a new field on my angular form and send the field(roles) to my UserController. The problem is with the params.require(:user).permit I couldn't get the values. Why ? It is happen please give me reference to me to know about this stuffs,

Answer (score 1):

your `roles` param is a Array so when whitelisting you should do like this:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :contact_number, :user_name, :password, :roles => [])
```

and `roles` should be nested inside `user` in params

your `user_params` is looking for params that is nested inside `user` key like `"user"=>{"first_name"=>"nifras", ....` from your posted params . But you can see, there is no `roles` key inside the `user` instead it is present as key of params not key of user of params so your `user_params` method will return only the part in side **{}** in below because that is params of user:

```
"user"=>{"first_name"=>"nifras", "last_name"=>"ismail", "email"=>"nifrasismail@gmail.com", "contact_number"=>"3778990300", "user_name"=>"ffgfg", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

But your roles param is outside of it

Comment: Could not understand on this term roles should be nested inside user in params

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks to notify the error on quickly. I will upvote you when i reached 15 reputation. Thanks again. Could you please give me some reference for rails learning

Comment: Best source for beginning would be the offical guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ . Go step by step and there you will find every section with detailed explanation and example. start from `getting started`. After completing this, you can follow https://www.railstutorial.org/book. About your current problem, this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters will be helpful

Comment: Thanks @sajan . It would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

User parameters should be nested under key `user`. And you receive some parameters nested under key `user` and some not.

1. Ensure `roles` parameter is nested under key `user`
2. Allow `roles` to be an array in controller.

Controller `user_params` method:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email,
    :contact_number, :user_name, :password, roles: [])
end
```